# How to compile and link against cddlib library?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, static-linking

I want to start a little c++ projekt that uses the library cddlib (http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/fukudak/cdd_home/cdd.html) which I installed (plus GMP) in a directory, say

```
/some/path/to/libcdd/
```

In a different directory, I have a file **main.cpp** with the contents

```
#include "setoper.h"
#include "cdd.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  fprintf(stdout, "start\n");

  dd_set_global_constants();  
  dd_free_global_constants();

  fprintf(stdout, "done\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Here, the two functions dd_... are functions from the library cddlib. I tried to compile this using the (naive?) command

```
g++ -o out main.cpp
```

However, this yields

```
/tmp/ccF7dx0W.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `dd_set_global_constants'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `dd_free_global_constants'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The same happens for the call

```
g++ -L/some/path/to/libcdd/lib -I/some/path/to/libcdd/include -lcdd main.cpp
```

Is this just a stupid mistake? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with g++ 4.8.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add cdd-path to your includes:

```
#include <cdd/setoper.h>
#include <cdd/cdd.h>
```

Next use following to compile:

```
g++ -o exe main.cpp -lcdd
```

Nothing else needed, if library is in system library dirs.

**Note:**`-lcdd` must be the last argument of the compiler command line to work correctly.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: If I reinstalled cddlib in the default dirs (with super-user rights) and with the default libgmp, it seems to work! Thanks @themole ! 

For the sake of completeness: I had to use
`#include <setoper.h>
#include <cdd.h>` instead of the given ones.

Comment: For me, with ubuntu 14.04 it was not sufficient to simply write `<cdd.h>`. I need to take the full one `<cdd/cdd.h>`.